# scale_x_discrete & disappearing labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
times=c(0:23)
               ggplot(TravelTimes, aes(x=Times))+labs(y="# Flights",x = "Times") + 
        scale_x_discrete( name ="hour",breaks=c(0:23),limits=times)+ ###lastchange
        geom_point(aes(y = TravelTimes[[2]], colour = "Arrivals",group=1))+
        geom_point(aes(y = TravelTimes[[3]], colour = "Departures",group=1))+
        geom_line(aes(y = TravelTimes[[2]], colour = "Arrivals",group=1))+
        geom_line(aes(y = TravelTimes[[3]], colour = "Departures",group=1))+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0))+ 
        scale_color_manual("legend", values = c("Departures" = colors[1], "Arrivals" = colors[2]))
```

TravelTimes looks as follows

```
   Times Arrivals Departures

1      0        0         88

2      1        0         25
3      2        0          4
4      3        0          2
5      4        0         43
6      5        0        487
7      6        0        915
8      7        0       1829
9      8        0       1617
10     9        0       1547
11    10        0       1498
12    11        0       1007
13    12        0       2001
14    13        0       1548
15    14        0       1156
16    15        0       1513
17    16        0       1157
18    17        0       1624
19    18        0       1280
20    19        0       1674
21    20        0       1640
22    21        0       1521
23    22        0        532
24    23        0        254
```

It works quite nicely and produces the following graph
      [click for correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZ5l.jpg)

However when I try changing "times" i run into problems with the labels disappearing

```
      times=c("12AM","1AM","2AM","3AM","4AM","5AM","6AM","7AM","8AM","9AM","10AM","11AM","12PM","1PM","2PM","3PM","4PM","5PM","6PM","7PM","8PM","9PM","10PM","11PM")
```

[click for incorrect graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w9tb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may edit `TravelTimes` accordingly:

```
TravelTimes$Times <- factor(times, levels = times)
```

where the usage of `levels` orders hours in the desired way. Then

```
ggplot(TravelTimes, aes(x = Times)) + labs(y = "# Flights") + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "hour") +
  ...
```

seems to give the desired output.

Comment: Thanks but if I do that, then the labels are misalligned. This happens for both charts. The charts will start at a point with no label in the x-axis.

Comment: @I.J.AbdulHakeem, right, see the update. Does it work well now?

Comment: Yeah, works well, though it should be used only for AM-PM time frame. Thanks!